# What is the best way to match three DB tables with unique time stamps?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have three tables that receive new information throughout the day from three data sources.

```
Table A     Table B     Table C
5, 8:00     J, 8:00     3, 8:00
6, 8:01     K, 8:02     8, 8:04
4, 8:03
9, 8:06
```

At the end of the day, I'd like to process the data chronologically where I need the most recent three pieces of information as any of the three timestamps change.  The result I'd want is like:

```
Table A     Table B     Table C     *Data As of*
5, 8:00     J, 8:00     3, 8:00     *8:00*
6, 8:01     J, 8:00     3, 8:00     *8:01*
6, 8:01     K, 8:02     3, 8:00     *8:02*
4, 8:03     K, 8:02     3, 8:00     *8:03*
4, 8:03     K, 8:02     8, 8:04     *8:04*
9, 8:06     K, 8:02     8, 8:04     *8:06*
```

I'm currently dumping 3 queries into 3 datatables.  Then I iterate thru all three at once by taking the earliest timestamp of the three.  This works, but is a bit cumbersome.  One table has about 3 million records per day, one has 200, and one has a handful.  Sometimes I process 20 days of data at a time.  Thoughts on the best approach?

Comment: Do you need the result of all three tables at once or is it ok to have one query per table?

Comment: You're somehow duplicating the rows into the result? What decides that 6 and 4 in A are twice, or K in B is 4 times?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it, you want a result for each minute, that takes the latest row from each table where the time is the reference time or smaller?

Comment: @JamesZ Actually it's for each unique time among the 3 tables.  Notice that 8:05 is not in the the tables or the result.

Comment: I do need all three pieces of information at once.  The example uses even seconds, but given the size of the table there are obviously timestamps w/ millisecond precision.

Comment: You can use **rownumber** to enumerate each row from each table ordered by the timestamp and join basead on that order

Answer (score 2):

This is at least one way to do it. Probably needs some analysis about the performance, but this assumes you create a table with the distinct times you have. If it's not enough to have this on minute level (or whatever you have on the table) you can of course do "insert into #time select distinct time ..." from each of the tables before running this, but that can be quite heavy too.

```
select distinct
  a.id as a_id,
  a.time as a_time,
  b.id as b_id,
  b.time as b_time,
  c.id as c_id,
  c.time as c_time
from
  time t

  outer apply (
    select top 1 id, time
    from tablea a
    where a.time <= t.time
    order by a.time desc
  ) a

  outer apply (
    select top 1 id, time
    from tableb b
    where b.time <= t.time
    order by b.time desc
  ) b

  outer apply (
    select top 1 id, time
    from tablec c
    where c.time <= t.time
    order by c.time desc
  ) c

order by 
  a_time, 
  b_time, 
  c_time
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de7ae/6

Answer (score 0):

Try next script (SQL2012+):

```
-- Step #1: it creates a table to store all distinct TS
CREATE TABLE #AllTS (TS DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY) -- Change type of TS column with the proper data type

-- Step #2: it inserts distinct (UNION) TS values
INSERT  #AllTS
SELECT  TS
FROM (
    SELECT TS FROM dbo.A
    UNION SELECT TS FROM dbo.B
    UNION SELECT TS FROM dbo.C
) x(TS)

-- Step #3: for every source table use bellow query to generate requested resultset
SELECT  MAX(y.Col1)OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID) AS Col1,
        MAX(y.TS)OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID) AS TS
FROM (
    SELECT  a.Col1, a.TS, SUM(CASE WHEN a.TS IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY x.TS) AS GroupID
    FROM    #AllTS x LEFT JOIN dbo.A a ON x.TS = a.TS
) y
```

Note 1: You should try to speed up above query using indexes created on every source table on `TS` column. Example:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_A_TS_#_Col1 ON dbo.A(TS) INCLUDE (Col1)
```

Note 2: Also, to improve performance of the last query you could test different joint hints:

```
#AllTS x LEFT HASH JOIN dbo.A -- Could be useful  when source tables are "big"
```

or

```
#AllTS x MERGE JOIN dbo.A
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b73a5)</kbd>